# Rails routing for nested controller's catch-all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In rails 3, how do I make all controllers/actions including nested controllers work without specifying them in routes.rb?

I uncommented the following line, but it doesn't work with nested controller.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

I want to make /preview/draft1/index work.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a route with a contraint on the controller:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :controller => /preview\/[^\/]+/
```

Where "preview" is the name of the namespace.

And then:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

For more info:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments